# Can "skim by" used this way?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, phrase-usage

A seemingly native English speaker said the following sentence on Youtube:

"...right now I'm not dead broke I don't have to skim by 4 any days"

Can "skim by" used this way as in "get by?"

Comment: You might get away with using "skim by" that way, but not "4".

Comment: Ah, so you can use "skim by" to mean "get by"? I couldn't find this definition anywhere on the internet.

Comment: I wonder if it’s a Malaprop for “skimp”

Comment: Ah, thanks Jim. That must have been it. Not sure how I did not catch that.

Comment: One might say "skimp by", "scrimp by", "scrape by", and several others.  "Skim by", while not particularly idiomatic, would generally be understood.

Comment: Neither 'skimp by' nor 'scrimp by' sound any more idiomatic than 'skim by' to me, though I can imagine the 'p' of 'skimp' getting lost in the 'b' if 'by'. Could the OP link to the video and give a time stamp?